# How do we populate a dropdown list's element from a variable in a collection in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I am actually trying to do 2 things here:

With 2 dropdown lists,
 a) the first would populate with the products, while
 b) the second would populate with the colors according to the first dropdown selected.

I starts off insert a document into the collection as below:

```
ProductList.insert ({ product: "apple", color: "\"red\",\"green\""});  
ProductList.insert ({ product: "banana", color: "\"yellow\",\"green\""});
```

And this is what I have so far:

**Main.html**

```
<template name="prodlist">
<select id="category-select">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please Select</option> 
        {{#each prodlist}}
            <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</template>

<template name="colorlist">
<select id="category-select">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please Select</option> 
        {{#each colorlist}}
            <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</template>
```

**Main.js**

```
Template.prodlist.helpers({
    prodlist: function(){
        return ProductList.find().map(function(doc) {
            return doc.product
        })
    }
});  

Template.colorlist.helpers({
colorlist: function(){
    return ProductList.find().map(function(doc) {
        return doc.color.split(",")  //<-- edited with MrE's answer
    })
```

The reason I insert `color: "\"red\",\"green\""` is trying to simulate when you populate the dropdown as hardcode:  `return ["red", "green"]`, but it return as one element with the string `"red","green"`.  Is there a better approach?  Also I don't know if there are packages exists that handle dropdown.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you try to code a string into an array instead of using an array? I'm not sure what that gets you.

If you 'really' want to use a string, you need to parse it ( with `doc.color.split(",")` ) into an array instead of doing `[doc.color]`

Comment: thanks but the answer gives the same result (i.e. 1 element of "red","green" instead of a list of 2 colors.  Is it possible to insert an array into collection and use it as the dropdown's element?

Comment: yes it is possible, which is what I suggested by saying why don't you use an array. `doc.color.split(",")` gives you an array, not sure what you did that it did not return an array. Use debugger to trace your code and find what is going on

Comment: I edited the post with your suggestion just to make sure if I got you correctly.  It does not change however

Comment: your new edit would then output an array of arrays. you want return doc.color.split(","), not return [doc.color.split(",")]. BTW map also returns an array, so this may not even be what you want. you should ProductList.findOne(id).color.split(","); to get the array in the one object, but frankly just save an array in the first place and avoid all this extra steps

Comment: yea with or without the [], it returns the same thing.  I would love to use a debugger but i'm on window with notepad++, not sure if there's one avail

Comment: this is client side code: use Google Chrome debugger to debug your client side code.  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: ProductList.findOne(id).color.split(","); works well!  I will try to insert an array instead.  Thanks a bunch